# Function call in for loop and static variable

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {

    int r() {
        static int num = 7;
        return num--;
    }

    for(r(); r(); r())
        printf("%d",r());

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 52. How i m getting the output is out of my knowledge this question what i had learned about static went totally wrong.

Comment: C does not have nested functions.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int r(){
  static int num = 7;
  return num--;
}

int main()
{
  for(r();r();r())
    printf("%d",r());

 return 0;
}
```

the static var is like a global var (I mean not in the stack) but only visible for the function *r*

the result is 52 because it prints 5 then 2

- the initial value of *num* is 7
- the *for* call a first time *r* (init part of the *for*), so *num* is decremented to be 6 and *r* returns 7 for nothing,
- the test is performed and *num* is again decremented to be 5 and because 6 is return and is not 0 the *for* continue,
- now the *print* is done with again a call decrementing *num* to 4 with the result 5 being printed
- *r* called (modif part of the *for*) decrementing *num* to 2 and returning 3 for nothing
- again the test decrementing *num* to 2 and returning 3 != 0 the loop continue
- again the *print* is done with again a call decrementing *num* to 1 with the result 2 being printed
- *r* called (modif part of the *for*) decrementing *num* to 0 and returning 1 for nothing
- the test is performed and *num* is again decremented to be -1 and because 0 is return by *r* the loop stops

Answer (score 0):

First time you run `r()` it will return 7, next time 6 and so on.
The for loop will stop when `r()` value is 0.
The code flow is:

```
r() // 7 [1st expression in the for loop]
if (!r()) stop for loop; // 6, so goes into for loop [2nd expression in the for loop]
print (r()) // 5
r() // 4 [3rd expression in the for loop]
if (!r()) stop for loop // 3, continues again
print (r()) // 2
r() // 1 [3rd expression in the for loop]
if (!r()) stop for loop // 0 so exits the for loop
```

It first prints 5, then 2 (without newlines), hence the output is 52.